# create 'streachy' effect for drop down box (select2) using css

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS.

I need to create a drop down box (using select2) followed by a button.

Both should be on one line (no line break in between them). 
Both are contained within a div element.

Upon resizing the screen, I want the select2 to be stretched up and consume\release the additional space, while the button remains fixed in size and in its location (right after the select2, not breaking to the next line). I need the select2 to have min-width and max-width values he can 'leave' in between.

I have googled and searched here, found many answers directing me to use `white-space:nowrap`, and `display: inline-block` but I keep failing to achieve my needs.

[Here is a fiddle containing my attempts](http://jsfiddle.net/TNabn/1):

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have updated your fiddle. `jsfiddle.net/TNabn/6/`
Let me know if this is appropriate as question is phrased slightly confusingly

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked very well. exactly what I was looking for